# XPages Dojo Data Grid Data Source

Tags: datagrid, xpages

is it possible to change the data source of DojoDataGrid with ftSearch result instead of Rest Services?

Or can i put this ftSearch result into Rest Services in order to use If i would like to use that Rest Service as the source of Dojo Data Grid

Regards
C.A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute an FTSearch with XPages's REST services out of the box.

Put your FTSearch-string into property "search":

```
        <xe:restService id="restService1">
            <xe:this.service>
                <xe:viewItemFileService ... 
                    search="yourSearchString*">
```

Comment: If i put my search results in to an array. does it work?